# Click button on row of the table and show values in modal-window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I make a web site with bootstrap and bootstrap table. To add element into boostrap-table I using php. The problem is when I click to the edit button doesn't show on modal-window the values of the row that I clicked.

I think that the problem is in the jquery code. I doing different test with the debbug console of the browser and I have seen that when I clicked it doesn't get the values of the row. I try it another info in the console and I showed correctly, ex: `console.log($(this).text());`

Please Could you help me to understand where is the problem?

Code:

```
      <div class="row">
        <?php  
                $conn = Conectarse("localhost", "5432", "addcom", "dbadmin", "Tibidabo");  
                //query
                $query = "SELECT * FROM produccion.ma_producto ORDER BY codigo ASC";
                $result = pg_query($conn, $query);  
                //se despliega el resultado  
                ?><table class='table-bordered' id='tableprod'
                               data-toggle='table'
                               data-toolbar='#toolbar'
                               data-show-refresh='true'
                               data-show-toggle='true'
                               data-sort-name='name'
                               data-sort-order='desc'
                               data-show-columns='true'
                               data-pagination='true'
                               data-search='true'>

                    <thead class='thead-inverse'>
                        <tr>  
                            <th data-field='seleccion' data-switchable='false' data-checkbox='true'></th>
                            <th data-field='estado' data-switchable='false'></th>
                            <th data-field='edicion' data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>EDICIÓ</th>  
                            <th data-field='pagina' data-sortable='true'>PÀGINA</th>  
                            <th data-field='codigo' data-sortable='true' data-switchable='false'>CODI</th>  
                            <th data-field='image' data-switchable='false'>IMATGE</th>
                            <th data-field='descripcion-cat' data-sortable='true'>DESCRIPCIÓ CAT</th> 
                            <th data-field='descripcion-esp' data-sortable='true'>DESCRIPCIÓ ESP</th> 
                            <th data-field='marca' data-sortable='true'>MARCA</th> 
                            <th data-field='gramaje' data-sortable='true'>GRAMATJE</th>
                            <th data-field='destacado' data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>DESTACAT</th> 
                            <th data-field='pvp-cat' data-sortable='true'>PVP-CAT</th> 
                            <th data-field='pvp-lev' data-sortable='true'>PVP-LEV</th> 
                            <th data-field='pvp-and' data-sortable='true'>PVP-AND</th>
                            <th data-field='pvp-cen' data-sortable='true'>PVP-CEN</th>
                            <th data-field='pvp-nor' data-sortable='true'>PVP-NOR</th>
                            <th data-field='pvp-vas' data-sortable='true'>PVP-VAS</th>
                            <th data-field='pvp-spar' data-sortable='true'>PVP-SPAR</th>
                            <th data-field='user' data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>USER</th>
                            <th data-field='fecha-mod' data-sortable='true' data-visible='false'>FECHA-MOD</th>
                            <th data-field='edit' data-sortable='false' data-switchable='false'>EDIT</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                <?php while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){ ?>  
                        <tr id='<?php echo $row[0]; ?>'>
                            <td></td>
                            <?php echo $estado = EstadoIcon($row[2]); ?>
                            <td name='edicion'><?php echo $row[1] ?></td>
                            <td name='pagina'><?php echo $row[3] ?></td> 
                            <td name='codigo'><?php echo $row[0] ?></td>  
                            <?php echo $imatge = AddImage($row[9]); ?> 
                            <td name='descripcion-cat'><?php echo $row[5] ?></td>
                            <td name='descripcion-esp'><?php echo $row[4] ?></td>
                            <td name='marca'><?php echo $row[6] ?></td> 
                            <td name='gramaje'><?php echo $row[7] ?></td>
                            <td name='destacado'><?php echo $row[8] ?></td> 
                            <td name='pvp-cat'><?php echo $row[10] ?></td>
                            <td name='pvp-lev'><?php echo $row[11] ?></td>  
                            <td name='pvp-and'><?php echo $row[12] ?></td>  
                            <td name='pvp-cen'><?php echo $row[13] ?></td> 
                            <td name='pvp-nor'><?php echo $row[14] ?></td>  
                            <td name='pvp-vas'><?php echo $row[15] ?></td> 
                            <td name='pvp-spar'><?php echo $row[16] ?></td>
                            <td name='user'><?php echo $row[17] ?></td>
                            <td name='fecha-mod'><?php echo $row[18] ?></td>
                            <td><button class='btn btn-xs edit btn-edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit'><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px">edit</i> </button></td>
                        </tr>  
                <?php }  ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table> 


<script>

var $table = $('#tableprod');

        $('#tableprod').click(function() {

            var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),

            $tdata = $row.find("td");

            console.log($(this).text());

            $.each($tdata, function(index, value) {
                alert ('Entró');
                console.log($(this).text()); 
                $( "input:eq(" + index + ")").val($(this).text());
            });
        });     

        </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event should be associated with button not the table :

```
$('.btn-edit').click(function() {

            var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),

            $tdata = $row.find("td");

            console.log($(this).text());

            $.each($tdata, function(index, value) {
                alert ('Entró');
                console.log($(this).text()); 
                $( "input:eq(" + index + ")").val($(this).text());
            });
            $('#edit').modal('show')
        });
```

Your edit button trigger the bootstrap modal : you could either remove `data-toggle='modal'` from your edit button and trigger the modal programatically in the click event `$('#edit').modal('show')` . Or use the modal events `show.bs.modal` as follow

```
$('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var $button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var $row = $button.closest("tr"),

        $tdata = $row.find("td");

        console.log($button.text());

        $.each($tdata, function(index, value) {
            alert ('Entró');
            console.log($(this).text()); 
            $( "input:eq(" + index + ")").val($(this).text());
        });
 });
```

Comment: It doesn't work the click event do not launch for this I use the other version $('#tableprod').click(function() {

Comment: This version it doesn't work $('#tableprod .btn-edit').click(function() { too.

Comment: I've updated my answer check the second option using modal events `show.bs.modal`

Comment: Now it's working! I am goint to find to show this info in the fields of the modal-window :)

Comment: Good luck :) , let me know if you need help on it!

Comment: Hello again :) I have tried to show image in modal-window but It doesn't work. I think that the problem is I can not recovery the attrib 'name' of the td tags to link to input forms of the window-modal. Could you help me?

Comment: Hi, I've check your HTML, I suggest to not use `name` attribute in `td`, it is not a valid attribute for `td` tags, use `data-name` instead and get its value like this : `$(this).data('name')`

Comment: If you are obligated to use `name` attribute in `td` tags you can always get its value using `attr` method : `$(this).attr('name')`

Comment: Ok thanks @Yacine at moment I have used the <td data-field='page'> and after in js: var field = $(this).data("field");