# asp.net mvc pop-up modal read from table row

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I can successfully read my selected table row to my pop-up modal but if I am going to move my button to dynamic reading of table row from javascript all of my fields will become empty or did not read the selected table.

Here my Javascript that build my table row together with my button update to call pop-up modal:

```
 $.get("/Home/GetItem", function (data) {
    tempDIM = JSON.parse(data);
    if (tempDIM[0]["status"] == "SUCCESS") {
        for (var i = 1; i < tempDIM.length - 1; i++) {
            $("#TableBody").append("<tr>" +
                "<th scope='row'>" + (i + 1) + "</th>" +
                "<td id='" + tempDIM[i]["id"] + "'>" + tempDIM[i]["id"] + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + tempDIM[i]["name"] + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + tempDIM[i]["address"] + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + tempDIM[i]["age"] + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + tempDIM[i]["status"] + "</td>" +
                '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Update</button></td>' +                        
                "</tr > ");
        }
    }
});
```

Modal:

```
<table class="table" style="margin-top:10px">
        <thead>
            <tr>                    
                <th>id</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>address</th>
                <th>age</th>
                <th>status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>



   <table class="table table-striped" id="tBody">
       <tbody id="TableBody"></tbody>
    </table>



 <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-target="#exampleModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><b>Update Selected Details</b></h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>id:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="id" disabled />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>name :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" disabled />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>address :</label>
                        <input type="text" id="address" disabled />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>age:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="age" disabled />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>status:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="status" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="SaveChanges()" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my script for reading the table:

```
 $(function () {
        $(".btn").click(function () {

            var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),       // Finds the closest row <tr>
                $tds = $row.find("td");             // Finds all children <td> elements

            $("#id").val($row.find('td:eq(0)').text())
            $("#name").val($row.find('td:eq(1)').text())
            $("#address").val($row.find('td:eq(2)').text())
            $("#age").val($row.find('td:eq(3)').text())
            $("#status").val($row.find('td:eq(4)').text())

        });
    });
```

Any suggestion or comments why I am getting null value from my pop-up modal. TIA

Comment: Try using `$.each()` instead of using `JSON.parse` and `for` loop to iterate the response. In which part you're getting null value?

Comment: all of my fields in modal are getting null value

Comment: Are you mean `tempDIM[0]["status"]` and other `tempDIM[0]["somekey"]` contains null instead of selected data? Can you provide `GetItem` action contents?

Comment: my GetItem is just  a query that returns a list and convert it to jason to be parse on table row

Comment: Also there's no `<table>` tag exist in your example snippet, is target table actually exists? Still figure out some missing pieces that you're not presented here but possible to make null values.

Comment: I updated now my question you can see now my table on top of my modal

Comment: Are your results return `[object Object]` (i.e. the table is not populated by rows from `JsonResult`)? Try putting `console.log(data)` and see if the `data` contains JSON string or list of objects.

Comment: yes I can see the data and confirmed it is not returning [Object Object], my suspect is my function on getting the id,name, etc is not reading. I tried alert the $row and see there is no result

Comment: Well, I assumed the table contains data at this point, hence I think you're using wrong selector and event handler. I provided the details in below example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed that your table contains proper data, `$(".btn").click()` event handler seems to be wrong because you may call other button with `class="btn"` outside the table row (i.e. `<button type="button" id="btnSave" ...>`). You should handle `show.bs.modal` event from `exampleModal` instead, then iterate row elements and put all values into corresponding `<input>` elements ordered by column index like example below:

```
$("#exampleModal").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var $button = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var $row = $button.closest("tr");
    var $tds = $row.find("td");

    $.each($tds, function(i, value) {
        $("input:eq(" + i + ")").val($(this).text());
    });
});
```

**Note:** If you want to submit textbox values inside the modal, avoid using `disabled` attribute which prevents the value from being posted, use `readonly` instead e.g. `<input type="text" id="id" readonly="readonly" />`.

Working example (simplified): [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KOwF7t)

Related issue:

[Click button on row of the table and show values in modal-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898940/click-button-on-row-of-the-table-and-show-values-in-modal-window)

Comment: I got it, very appreciate it!